# Need to build a power supply from 127v AC to 3 DC outputs

Tags: power-supply, ac-dc

I need to build a power supply that takes 127v AC and outputs 3 DC voltages: +90V, +1.4V, -4.5V. It is for a small tube amp, actually I'm powering the amp with batteries. I general terms, can you please tell me what components I will need and how to build it? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to build it yourself? Can't you use standard AC/DC supplies (not wall-warts, but these metal screw-terminal supplies [like this one](https://www.meanwell.co.uk/imager/products/7372/RSD-30_963afa1c20b288d6919519f8dc8a9a31_f5a916fdd99b71180a2d268c9f40d8f3.jpg)?)

Comment: Add to your question the current of each voltages you want to generate. Do you need 10A or only 0.1mA ? This decides which components or circuits are useful in this case.

Comment: Include more details. Tell us the necessary current for each voltages.

Comment: Thanks, about 50mA for 1.4v and 10mA for the others.

Comment: What about the tube filaments?  Also, you mention powering the amp with both an AC source and batteries.  Which is it?

Comment: The tube filaments are 1.4v, 100mA max current. Actually the entire amp is powered by batteries (cells). I want to replace the batteries by a custom power supply. The input AC voltage will be 127v and I need the outputs of +90v, +1.4v, -4.5v DC, replacing the voltages actually supplied by batteries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just found the exact answer I needed here: https://antiqueradio.org/art/PowerSupplySchematic.jpg

The amp is very similar to those antique tube radios, so this schematic should do what I need. Thanks all.

Comment: This really isn't that good a power supply. Probably a bit better than what vacuum tube stuff typically used, though.

Comment: (With a 2k2 series resistor, I'd put the 100 μF on the output side and about 22 μF as a load capacitor. Or use a 220 Ω load resistor and 2k series for lower peak current, still.)